# Why are MM-1QFA strictly more powerful than MO-1QFA?

Tags: finite-automata, quantum-computing

While dealing with quantum finite automata (QFA), I repeatedly come across the statement that measure-many QFA (MM-1QFA, [KW97](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/Papers/QuantumFiniteAutomata.pdf)) are **strictly** more powerful than measure-once QFA (MO-1QFA, [MC97](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9707031.pdf)); both models are sufficiently described in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_finite_automata).

So far, I found a proof in [L19](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3301.pdf) (p.5, prop.1) which shows that, for any MO-1QFA and any input string *w*, there is an MM-1QFA accepting *w* with the same probability (only bounded error considered here). Therefore, MO-1QFA = MM-1QFA.
However, I have not been able to find a proof showing that MM-1QFA > MO-1QFA indeed. There are informal arguments by Brodsky and Pippenger [BP18](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9903014.pdf) (p.9, start of sec.4), just saying that this is because MM-1QFA are allowed to terminate before reading the entire input string (due to their measurements after every transition). Furthermore, Ambainis and Freivalds [AF98](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9802062.pdf) (end of p.3) say that any finite language can be recognized by MM-1QFA, but no finite non-empty language can be recognized by MO-1QFA.

Though these claims seem reasonable to me at first, I have failed to construct an example (let alone an idea for a general proof) that would make them clear to me. One issue is that I do not see how a MM-1QFA would know "when to stop".

Based on all this, I would be glad if someone could help me to see why MM-1QFA are strictly more powerful than MO-1QFA.